# Sometimes the updated rows are not locked within instead of update trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, trigger, locking

Here is as small repro:

```
create table dbo.t (id int primary key, v int);
insert into dbo.t values (1, 1), (2, 2);

create table dbo.s (id int primary key, v int);
insert into dbo.s values (1, 10);
go

create trigger dbo.tr_t__iou
on dbo.t
instead of update
as
begin
 set nocount on;

 exec sp_lock @@spid;
end;
go

update dbo.t set v = 10 where id = 1;

update t
 set
  v = 10
from
 dbo.s s join
 dbo.t t on t.id = s.id;

update t
 set
  v = 10
from
 (values (1, 10)) s(id, v) join
 dbo.t t on t.id = s.id;
go

drop table dbo.t, dbo.s;
go
```

`sp_lock` within the `trigger` reports U-`key lock` on the affected row in the first and the last cases, but in the second case there is no `lock` at all, how can it be explained?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the update statement qualifies for a trivial plan, the optimizer rule that expands the instead-of trigger part of the statement (`ExpandInsteadOfTriggerUpd`) includes the part of the plan that reads from the base table. This rewrite includes adding an `UPDLOCK` hint to the base read. As usual, the `UPDLOCK` hint means that update locks are taken and held to the end of the transaction.

When the statement does not qualify for a trivial plan, the `ExpandInsteadOfTriggerUpd` rule only [rewrites the write-cursor portion](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/09/sql-plan/instead-of-triggers) of the plan, leaving the base table reads untouched - no `UPDLOCK` hint is added.

My guess is that this trivial plan behaviour exists to avoid a deadlock scenario.

Comment: Thank you Paul, but what about inserted/deleted in trigger that can differ from what we have in the table right now? Does it mean that in case of non-trivial plan we potentially can have "lost update"?

Comment: @sepupic Instead of triggers definitely complicate thinking about isolation levels, but it's really a timing difference and remember the instead of trigger can do anything it likes *instead of* the original operation. If the concerns are valid in your real scenario, you could add an `UPDLOCK` hint manually or use a higher isolation level. Under read committed, SQL Server need not take any long term locks when reading. The `U` locks you often see are for conversion deadlock avoidance and are scoped to the statement not the txn. Long separate discussion.

Comment: Does this mean that in every update from join one should **always** add a hint to updating table as in some second moment this table can get instead of update trigger on it? Isn't it a bug since it's **not documented** that inserted/deleted guarantee no consistency with what was in update itself, i.e. one **cannot rely** on these tables within instead of update trigger? There is no word about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15 under "Using the inserted and deleted Tables in INSTEAD OF Triggers"

Comment: @sepupic If that's the guarantee you want then yes you might need a hint or higher isolation level. I can't really understand the rest of your comment, but I would say it is the responsibility of the person adding the trigger to ensure everything works. Anyway, this is all a tangent from your original question, which I have answered. You can ask follow-up questions of course.